# Elseifs being ignored after first if

Tags: lua

i was trying to do this function in a game, but i'm having problem with it

Basically all these Container functions are right, the problem is the lua itself.

the only problem is that the last two elseifs are being ignored after the first if is done

```
function withdrawAmmo(from, to) 
    local ammoCount = Container(to):ItemCount(ammoID) + Self.Ammo().count
    print("Current Ammo : " .. ammoCount)
    local last = Container.GetLast()
    Walker.Stop()
    Self.OpenDepot()
    last:UseItem(from, true)
    print(" Ammo in this backpack : " .. last:ItemCount(ammoID))
    while last:ItemCount(ammoID) > 0 or ammoCount < maxAmmo do
        last:MoveItemToContainer(0, to, 0, 100)
        wait(800, 1200)
    end
    if ammoCount < maxAmmo then
        EnoughAmmo = false
        repeat
            print "Trying to find more ammo"
            for spot = last:ItemCount() - 1, 0, -1 do
                if Item.isContainer(last:GetItemData(spot).id) then
                    last:UseItem(spot, true)
                    wait(400, 800)
                    break
                end
            end
            last:MoveItemToContainer(0, to, 0, 100)
            wait(800, 1200)
        until ammoCount >= maxAmmo or not Container.GetLast():isFull()
    elseif ammoCount >= maxAmmo then EnoughAmmo = true 
        print("Enough ammo, continuing") 
        Walker.Start()
    elseif not EnoughAmmo then 
        print("You don't have enough ammo!, stoping script...")
        Walker.Stop()
    end
end
```

Walker.Start() continues the script, after the first if is done the script continues somehow but doesn't print "You don't have enough ammo!, stoping script..." or "Enough ammo, continuing"

Comment: Are you coming back with every single step today? Deleting your questions directly after the steps doe not make it better.

Comment: `elseif` is by definition only considered after the `if` condition failed. RTFM.

Comment: @Deduplicator i thought thats what i should do since my other code was no longer what i was using

Comment: @Deduplicator I think the OP is trying to do the right thing, it can take some time to figure out what's the right way on SO. He/she did the right thing deleting previous question as it was completely different from this one (although on the same Lua file, the code changed quite a bit -- presumably as result of debugging).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding about what the `if-elseif` construction does.

It only executes the code under **one** of the conditions. It will test the subsequent conditions **if and only if** the first is false. Once it finds a condition that is true, it will execute the code under that condition and then go to the code after the `end`.

Let me explain using an example. You have an `if-elseif` block that looks like this:

```
if y = z then
    print "y and z are equal (if)"
elseif y = z then
    print "y and z are equal (elseif)"
end
```

If `y = 2` and `z = 2`. When your program gets to the `if-elseif` block, it will test the first condition (`if y = z`). If it is true, it will execute whatever is in the block. Then it will go on to whatever is after `end`. **The second condition (`elseif y = z`) is never tested *because the first was true* and the second `print` statement will never be executed.**

Here is another example, but this program will print `y and z are equal` twice:

```
if y = z then
    print "y and z are equal"
end

if y = z then
    print "y and z are equal"
end
```

---

## What You Want to Do Instead

Because you want the second and third conditions to be tested, you need to put them into separate `if` blocks like this:

```
if ammoCount < maxAmmo then
    // do stuff here
end

if ammoCount >= maxAmmo then
    EnoughAmmo = true 
    print("Enough ammo, continuing") 
    Walker.Start()
end

if not EnoughAmmo then 
    print("You don't have enough ammo!, stoping script...")
    Walker.Stop()
end
```

Comment: that was very insightful, thanks a lot!